# Can I keep array of string as RawValue of case in enum?

Tags: swift, enums

I want to keep array as a rawValue in enum base but I get an error like this:

> Raw type '[String]' is not expressible by a string, integer, or floating-point literal

Can someone provide help with this?

The enum that I need.

```
enum PaymentState: [String] {
    case pending = ["first", "second"]
}
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. Use a computed property instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve that kind of style, you can use `RawRepresentable`

```swift
enum PaymentState: RawRepresentable {
    typealias RawValue = Array<String>

    init?(rawValue: Array<String>) {
        if rawValue == ["first", "second"] {
            self = .pending
        }
        return nil
    }

    var rawValue: Array<String> {
        switch self {
        case .pending:
            return ["first", "second"]
        }
    }

    case pending
}

PaymentState.pending.rawValue // ["first", "second"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternate solution you have is:

```swift
enum PaymentState {
    case pending
    
    var list: [String] {
        switch self {
            case .pending:
                return ["first", "second"]
        }
    }
}
```

You can access it using `PaymentState.pending.list`. This solution makes it easier to extend your enum with more cases. Just add cases with return values within the switch.